# Number grouping regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex:

```
\b((?:12345)(\d{1,4})1)\b
```

What I'm trying to do is make it so the end of the number must always be 1 regardless of the range or choice of numbers in between.  What I'm having a difficult time figuring out is how to get around an example like **12345 111 1**,(Note: I've separated the grouped numbers to avoid confusion).  How can I make it so the regex can tell the numbers in the range group apart from the '1' that follows the group??  Thank you for your help.

UPDATE:

No specific programming language, the regex is being stored in a database and being pulled and used as a reference check by Javascript.

UPDATE:

Some Examples to clarify:

-A user enters **1234511**, how would the regex engine know if that's valid or not?? i.e. How does the engine know if it's valid **12345 1 1**(a single '1' with the required ending '1') or invalid **12345 11** (the group of 1's are part of the `(\d{1,4})` portion of the regex, but the string doesn't include the '1' at the end)

-A user enters **1234510111**, this would be valid.  **12345 1011 1**(the '1011' is part of the group `(\d{1,4})`) and includes the 1 at the end.

Summary:

The regex must recognize any group of numbers ranging from 1-4, but the string must always end with a 1

Comment: It's already in it's own group: http://www.rubular.com/r/2yIrkwQ2G4

Comment: I still dont understand what you want to achieve. Can you please give one more example of input and expected output.

Comment: As Kobi pointed out in his comment and answer your regex is exactly doing what you want. I still dont see the problem. Its just not the first, but the second group. Use `/\b12345(\d{1,4})1\b/` as Kobi answered and you have it in the first group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex already captures those numbers into a capturing group:

```
var str = "123459991";
var match = str.match(/\b((?:12345)(\d{1,4})1)\b/);

alert(match[2]); // 999
```

Capturing groups are the parentheses you have on your regex.

- Group 0  has the whole match *by default* (always `matches[0]`, for every regular expression)
- Group 1 is `((?:12345)(\d{1,4})1)`, which is the whole match again (not too useful).
- Group 2 is `(\d{1,4})`, which is the number you're looking for.
- `12345` is **not** captured to a group - `(?...)` is a *non-capturing group*, and isn't included in the as a token in the results. Again, this doesn't add much, you could simple write `12345`.

You can simplify the regex to `/\b12345(\d{1,4})1\b/` and not lose any information.

**How is it matched:**
Generally, it's important to remember the regex engine *tries really hard to match your input*. Specifically, it tries all combinations (and all possible starting positions) until it can match the pattern to the text.
For example, if the text is 1234599991, matching is easy:

- match 12345 (character by character, of course)
- match \d{4} against 9999
- match 1

Next example: 123459991

- match 12345
- match \d against 9
- match \d against 9
- match \d against 9
- match \d against 1
- try to match 1, but fail (it was already consumed by \d{4})
- **backtrack**  the last matched character:

  - no \d{1,4} matched 999
  - 1 can be matched.
- done.

See also: [Backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Implementations_and_running_times), [Greediness and Laziness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Nalum/KrTJe/) see if it achieves what you want.

```
var regex = /^(([0-9]{5})([0-9]{1,4})(1))$/i;
var match1 = "1234511111".match(regex);
var match2 = "123451111".match(regex);
var match3 = "12345111".match(regex);
var match4 = "1234511".match(regex);
var match5 = "123451".match(regex);

console.log(match1);
console.log(match2);
console.log(match3);
console.log(match4);
console.log(match5);
```